# Question about Sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I am Dealing with this question " Let $\rho:  $G$  \longrightarrow$ $Sym(G)$ be the regular representation
of the finite group $G$. Show that $\rho (G) \leq Alt(G)$ if and
only if a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ is not cyclic." 
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Well the image of an element of order $k$ under $\rho$ consists of $|G|/k$ cycles of length $k$, which is an odd permutation if and only if $k$ is even and $|G|/k$ is odd.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok that is good but what the relation between this and that the 2-sylow subgroup is not cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\;P_2\;$ be a Sylow $\;2-$ subgroup of $\;G\;,\;\;|G|=2^nm\;,\;\;m=1\pmod 2$ , then

$$P_2=\langle x\rangle\implies \rho(x)=\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdot\ldots\cdot\sigma_m$$

where $\;\sigma_i\;$ is a $\;|P_2|=2^n-$ cycle. But then $\;\rho(x)\notin Alt(G)\;$ as a product of an odd  number ($\;m\;$) of even cycles (and thus odd permutations).

I leave the other direction to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, For the other direction, I try to do it by cotrapositive proof i.e I assume that $\;\rho(x)$ is an odd but I cannot conclude that P2 is cyclic.

Comment: $\;\rho(x)\notin Alt(G)\implies\;\rho(x)\;$ is the product of $\;|G|/ord(x)\;$ cycles each of length $\;ord(x)\;$ and thus $\;ord(x)\;$ is even and $\;|G|/ord(x)\;$ is odd (see Derek's comment above). If $\;|G|=2^nm\;,\;(2,m)=1\;$ , this means $\;ord(x)=2^nm'\;$ , with $\;m'\mid m\;$ . Now remember that any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic...